# .htaccess to forward url and exclude one page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How to write a .htaccess that has in result:

ALL Requests on that domain go forwarded to the index.html at the rootfolder of the same domain.

The index.html itself is not forwarded (excluded) as it includes 2 outbound links.

thanks
chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index\.php
RewriteRule /?(.*) index.html [L]
```